# Java The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: java, variables, arrays

I got a problem here. I got error that The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable. But i don't understand where is the problem. And btw there are a lot of JSONarrays, i just put one for an example.

```
public class As
{

static JSONArray temp0=new JSONArray();


public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException 
{
      arrayValues(0)=new JSONArray(); //The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
}
 public static JSONArray arrayValues(int ip)
    {
        switch (ip)
        {
            case 0:
            return temp0;
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Thank you guys

Comment: `==` - are you sure you mean that?

Comment: A basic java tutorial will be a good start my friend.

Comment: @BitNinja: `arrayValues` appears to be a method here...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Indeed it is! I just assumed based on the name...

Comment: @user3930508: No-one is saying you're stupid.  But you have posted code that doesn't correspond to the error you're claiming you get.

Comment: What is your interpretation of `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable`?

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?  You run the method, to get a `JSONArray`.  You make another new `JSONArray`.  What would it actually mean to assign one to the other?  This doesn't really make any sense, which is why you get the message.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems in :

`arrayValues(0)==new JSONArray()`

1. `==` is not assignment. `=` is
2. you can't assign to the value returned by a method call. You can only assign to a variable.

Though based on the error you got, #1 is probably a typo in your question, and you did use `=`.

You can write

```
JSONArray var = new JSONArray();
```

or

```
JSONArray var = arrayValues(0);
```

but not

```
arrayValues(0)=new JSONArray();
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, i ment "=", but i wont work

Comment: @user3930508 In that case, the only problem is #2

Comment: But what would be the solution then?

Comment: @user3930508 That depends entirely on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well what i am trying to do is that i got a lot of JSONarrays and using switch will be easy to get them.

Comment: @user3930508 You can use the switch statement in your `arrayValues` method, but you must assign the value it returns to a variable.

Comment: and how i am going to do that?:D

Comment: @user3930508 `JSONArray var = arrayValues(0);`

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your code `arrayValues(0)==new JSONArray();`

You need to know

1. How java array works -- please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html
2. what is == and =? -- == is for comparison and = is for assignment

Comment: Sorry my bad, i meant "="